# Any way to optimise latest record for a group query in MySQL for 30+ million row table?

Tags: mysql

I know variants of this question have been asked a few times but I have tried the solutions offered like using the join or subquery approaches, etc and I'm still facing performance issues.

I have a table with about 20,000 stocks, and a total number of records exceeding 30+ million.

Here is the create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `prices` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `StockID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Price` decimal(18,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UX_StockID_Date` (`StockID`,`Date`),
  KEY `IX_StockID` (`StockID`),
  KEY `IX_Date` (`Date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I need to simply be able to get the prices of all stocks on any given day. The issue I face is due to low trading / holidays / weekends, there are often days where a given stock will not trade so I cannot simply query by an exact date. I still need to get the price of the stock on the last day prior to that day in the event that the stock has not traded on the day.

I have tried the join and subquery approaches, but they don't give great performance.

For example, my code for the join approach is:

```
select P.*
from (
    SELECT StockID, Max(Date) As MaxDate
    FROM prices
    WHERE Date <= '2020-12-31'
    GROUP BY StockID
) as P1
join prices as P on P.StockID = P1.StockID and P.Date = P1.MaxDate;
```

Here is the explain statement result for this query:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '1' | 'PRIMARY' | '' | NULL | 'ALL' | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | '48731' | '100.00' | 'Using where' |
| '1' | 'PRIMARY' | 'P' | NULL | 'eq_ref' | 'UX_StockID_Date,IX_StockID,IX_Date' | 'UX_StockID_Date' | '9' | 'P1.StockID,P1.MaxDate' | '1' | '100.00' | NULL |
| '2' | 'DERIVED' | 'prices' | NULL | 'range' | 'UX_StockID_Date,IX_StockID,IX_Date' | 'UX_StockID_Date' | '9' | NULL | '48731' | '100.00' | 'Using where; Using index for group-by' |

This works accurately but is very slow (over 1-2 minutes for the query) due to the large size of the table. Performance improves on subsequent tries as InnoDB starts caching the table in memory but caching is not what I want to rely on.

Is there any way I can optimise this query to improve performance? Or is there any additional view/table I can create to be able to dynamically get this data in the most optimal manner?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249183/discussion-on-question-by-aks94-any-way-to-optimise-latest-record-for-a-group-qu).

Answer (score 0):

```
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
UNIQUE KEY `UX_StockID_Date` (`StockID`,`Date`),
KEY `IX_StockID` (`StockID`),
```

==>

```
PRIMARY KEY(`StockID`,`Date`),
```

and get rid of `id` and all uses of it.

**Explanation**

Secondary keys (`UNIQUE` or not) take two steps to fetch other columns.  First is a BTree lookup in the index's BTree.  Ad the leaf node of that, the `PRIMARY KEY` column(s) (`id` in your case) is found.  Then the PK is used to reach into the data's BTree to find the full row.

Effectively, you have a BTree with 3 columns (and sorted on those 3 columns:  `StockID, Date, ID`

For small tables and few-row queries, bouncing back and forth between two BTrees is not very costly.  But I expect some of your queries to be fetching lots of rows, and the table may grow to be big.

With `PRIMARY KEY(StockID, Date)` there is only one BTree lookup.  At the leaf node, all the columns are right there.  Also, note that the `PRIMARY KEY` is a uniqueness constraint and an index.

Some likely queries --

```
SELECT ... WHERE StockID = 123 AND DATE between...
    -- Very efficient; note that the desired rows will be "clustered" together.

INSERT ...
    -- Although `INSERT` is not a big deal, it is even faster
       because there is only one index, not 3, to update.
       Also, it is faster because non-unique key updates are 'delayed'.
```

Another point...  The "clustering" aluded to above will become quite important if the table becomes so big that more disk blocks (16KB each) need to be fetched for the `SELECT` than will fit in `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  It looks like your table is only 5GB or so, including indexes.  (Or about 3GB with my changes.)  What is the value of that setting?  (This question is to address whether your data has gotten so big that "performance has fallen off a cliff".  My index changes will help avoid the problem in *most* stock queries.)

Side issues:

- Are the datetime values really `DATE`?  If not, then `<= '2020-12-31'` excludes all trades on New Year's Eve.  Suggest using `< 2021-01-01`, which will work 'correctly' with all date datatypes.
- `StockID` could be shrunk by one byte to `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` (limited to 16M values), thereby saving 90MB in your case or 30Mb in my case.
- "A bit, sure, but not that much longer" -- Yes, that much longer--because of the extra BTree lookup just to get the Price.

Comment: Sure, but what benefit would that add? The unique key composite index already exists on StockID, Date but it's not helping performance right?

Comment: @aks94 - I elaborated.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed explanation Rick! I will try out the index change (and removal of ID column). Just for clarification, after this change, would you recommend using the same query where I join the prices table with the max date by StockID subquery that I have shown above? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @aks94 - Yes, there is a much more efficient way to "get the max price over likely date ranges such as monthly and yearly".  Build and maintain a "summary" table of monthly min, max, tot_vol, etc.  See [_Summary Tables_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) .  [Start a new Question if you want to dig deeper into that.]

Comment: Thanks Rick but I don’t want to get the max price, rather I want to get the latest price before a given date in case of a missing record for that given date, hence the max(Date) approach. If you look at the query in my question, it achieves this but has a performance issue as number of records gets large. Would the primary key change as per your suggestion improve the performance of that query?

Comment: Doh!  Yes, _last_ price, not _max_.  The Summary table won't help.  But the changes to the indexes is still a valid recommendation.  Your `price` is what others call "close"?  (See also, "open", "high", and "low".)  Or are you looking at Mutual Funds, which have only one price per day?

Comment: Yes exactly, closing price is what I’m looking for on any given date even if it’s a holiday and there’s no record for it